# Set encoding for filter() call in gradle copy task

Tags: groovy, gradle, character-encoding

Let's say there is this sample groovy code in my `build.gradle`:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task doSomeFiltering(type: Copy) {
    from 'some/directory'
    into 'some/target'

    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [SAMPLE: '123abc456'])
}
```

If I had some Unicode characters in the copied and filtered files, they would be turned into the system default encoding in the output files, which creates some big problems if unicode-specific characters are used and the files are expected to stay in unicode.

So the problem is: This sample code does not respect custom encoding choices, it will always default to the system default for outputting the files after filtering. How can I set the encoding of the Reader/Writer that the filter uses?

Is it possible to work around this limitation, e.g. call
Apache Ant directly?

Comment: known issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1267

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specifying the encoding for filter calls was not natively supported by Gradle prior to version 2.14. Since Gradle 2.14, you can use the `filteringCharset` attribute of the `Copy` task, like this:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task doSomeFiltering(type: Copy) {
    from 'some/directory'
    into 'some/target'

    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'

    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [SAMPLE: '123abc456'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to work around this limitation by calling Apache Ant directly.

```groovy
task doSomeFiltering << {
    ant.copy(todir: 'some/target', encoding: 'utf8', outputencoding: 'utf8') {
        fileset(dir: 'some/directory')
        filterchain {
            replacetokens {
                token(key: 'SAMPLE', value: '123abc456')
            }
        }
}
```

The following is a more generic approach, you can use any filter:

```
task doSomeFiltering << {
    ant.copy(todir: 'some/target', encoding: 'utf8', outputencoding: 'utf8') {
        fileset(dir: 'some/directory')
        filterchain {
            filterreader(classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens') {
                param(type: 'token', name: 'SAMPLE', value: '123abc456')
            }
        }
}
```

Note that this `filterreader` call is a convenience method provided by Ant [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacetokens) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij33s.png)).

---

If you want to customize your gradle ant call, you can pretty much use Ant's XML syntax:

```xml
<filterchain>
    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
        <param type="token" name="SAMPLE" value="123abc456"/>
    </filterreader>
</filterchain>
```

turns into

```groovy
filterchain {
    filterreader(classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens') {
        param(type: 'token', name: 'SAMPLE', value: '123abc456')
    }
}
```

That way you can use properties and features described in the official documentation of ant, like these:

- [`FilterChain`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html)
- [`Copy`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)
- [`ReplaceTokens`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacetokens)

If you just "convert" the syntax provided there into the one that's required for gradle, it's possible to have great control over any ant call.